# help needed with a proof in <etale cohomology> by milne

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

> P23: Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be locally of finite-type. Prove that if $\Delta:Y\to Y\times Y$  is an open immersion, then $f$ is unramified.

$\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{spec}}$
... we reduce the problem to the case of a morphism $f:Y\to \spec k$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $y$ be a closed point of $Y$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, there exists a section $g:\spec k\to Y$ whose image is $\{y\}$. **(why?)**

...$\{y\}$ is open in $Y$. Moreover, $\spec\mathcal{O}_y=\{y\}\to \spec k$ still has the property that $\spec\mathcal{O}_y\to \spec\mathcal{O}_y\otimes\mathcal{O}_y$ is an open immersion. **($\spec\mathcal{O}_y$ is not $V(y)$, why do we have $spec\mathcal{O}_y={y}$,and I cannot prove the rest of the statement.)**

But $\mathcal{O}_y$ is an artin ring with residue field $k$ **(why $k(y)=k$ ?)** and $\spec\mathcal{O}_y\otimes\mathcal{O}_y$ has only one point. So $\mathcal{O}_y\otimes\mathcal{O}_y\to\mathcal{O}_y$ must be an isomorphism. **(how can we characterize the struction of $\mathcal{O}_y\otimes\mathcal{O}_y$?)**

Comment: Why $k=k(y)$: since $Y\to \mathrm{Spec} k$ is locally of finite-type, if $y$ is a point of $Y$, then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_y$ is finite-type over $k$.  In particular, if $y$ is a closed point, then $k(y)$ is finite type over $k$.  But the only field of finite type over an algebraically closed $k$ is $k$ itself; this is one form of the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: I had a go at improving the formatting, but I might have broken some of the LaTeX. If someone knows how to fix it please feel free to edit